# CSS Selectors for Scrapy Web Scraping

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm currently trying to scrape all the malls listed on the website

https://web.archive.org/web/20151112172204/http://www.simon.com/mall

using Python and Scrapy. I can't figure out how to extract the text "Anchorage 5th Avenue Mall".

```html
<div class="st-country-padding">
    <h4><a class="no-underline" href="/web/20151112172204/http://www.simon.com/search/alaska%2b(ak)" title="View Malls In Alaska">Alaska</a></h4>
        <div>
            <a href="/web/20151112172204/http://www.simon.com/search/anchorage,+ak" title="Malls in Anchorage, AK">Anchorage</a>:
                <a href="http://www.simon.com/mall/anchorage-5th-avenue-mall" title="View Anchorage 5th Avenue Mall Website">Anchorage 5th Avenue Mall</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a number of differnet attempts including

```
response.css("a::attr(title)").extract()
```

But doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

Note that Anchorage is just the name of the first mall so I can't call that directly because there are 200 or so different malls

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is.  There's no error in any code. Also, I think the screen shot adds clarity to my question

Comment: @WhiteDillPickle: Rob is saying that the screenshot of the DOM view should be reproduced as code, as it doesn't quite need to be in a screenshot (the image may become unavailable for any number of reasons such as server or network issues, rendering the question unanswerable when that context is lost). You can do that by right-clicking the outer element and choosing Copy Outer HTML. I've done that for you.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

`::attr(title)` gives you the value of the `title` attribute. What you want is the text, so you need to use `::text` instead.

Also, there doesn't appear to be a good way to identify the `a` element you want since it doesn't have anything that distinguishes it from the others, so a bit of pathing is necessary. Let me know if this works for you:

```
response.css(".st-country-padding > div > a:last-of-type::text").extract()
```

Comment: Not quite, its actually only picking up
            "Anchorage"
and all the other cities where the malls are located but not the mall names themselves.

Comment: What might be easier would be to just extract the Title from the second a element, hence just get - "View Anchorage 5th Avenue Mall Website"